# How to use if else for a controller variable on twig

Tags: symfony, twig

What im trying to do is compare the imageowner (variable returned by the controller) with the current user

```
<!-- image remove button --> 
 {% if {{ imageOwner }} == {{ app.user.username }} %} //Line 5
    <p>You are the owner of this image</p>

    <button onclick="deleteStuff()">deleted</button>
 {% endif %}
```

but it throws this error

```
A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" inLayoutBundle:Frontpage:content-bubble.html.twig at line 5
```

the {{ imageOwner }} and {{ app.user.username }} return the right values, I think its a syntax or logical error

Comment: You don't need `{{ }}` when you are in a statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 {% if imageOwner  == app.user.username %} //Line 5
    <p>You are the owner of this image</p>

    <button onclick="deleteStuff()">deleted</button>
 {% endif %}
```

`{{ imageOwner }}` is slimier to `echo $imageOwner` in php. So you do not need to wrap variable with `{{}}` when you don't want to print it.

Comment: This is not wrong, but this blatantly lacks of explanations

Comment: no it actually works! 
but I can only accept the answer in a few minutes